# Determining the sign of an int using shifts?

Tags: c, signed, bit

Here's the question

- sign - return 1 if positive, 0 if zero, and -1 if negative
- Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
- Max ops: 10
- Rating: 2

I thought of shifting to the right by 31 to grab the sign bit but can't 0 be positive AND negative technically?

Comment: Its not clear to me why this is being marked down.  The question is clear, the asker has described the problem and an attempt.  At least offer a reason why.

Comment: @ryyker that smells like "please do my homework"

Comment: To answer OP's "...can't 0 be positive AND negative... ?"  Mathematically, 0 could be considered dual-signed, sign-less, only positive, etc.  Many models exist.  Given "return 1 if positive, 0 if zero, and -1 if negative", the goal is clear as what to return when given 0.  Consider this a small lesson in programming requirements: The objective is well stated (hurrah - you are lucky), but the larger goal could be interpreted differently.  Do you quietly code to spec and/or raise an issue with the [customer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_customer_is_always_right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this for `32 bit int`:-

```
(x >> 31) | (((~x + 1) >> 31) & 1)
```

Comment: Shifting negative integers is implementation defined behavior in C, so any answer shifting the `int` is generally incorrect. Though, if you assume the range of `int` is as if two's complement encoding is used (or if two's complement is used), then casting the `int` to `unsigned int` first will work (due to the modular behavior of converting to an unsigned integer type).